# Secure requests to .html files in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, middleware, static-files

I have a web application written in ASP.NET Core. Authentication is done by checking if the Session contains a Json object that is obtained from a webservice at the first request. (using public/private keys etc.)

Inside this Json object is a number that corresponds with a physical folder beneath the Web root folder.

So, when a user accessing files within this folder it should check if this is allowed. In fact, there is a whole static website within this folder, so every request to an .html file has to be checked, before served.

I guess this can be done using some custom middleware, but I'm unsure where to start.

Anyone has a clue on how to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

The only real way is to proxy the HTML files through an action that *is* authorized. For example. Instead of linking directly to `foo.html`, you'd like to something like `/proxy?file=foo.html`, where `/proxy` would be an action that checks whether the user is actually authorized to view `foo.html` or not.

A similar approach is laid out in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.2#static-file-authorization):

> The Static File Middleware doesn't provide authorization checks. Any files served by it, including those under wwwroot, are publicly accessible. To serve files based on authorization:
>
> - Store them outside of wwwroot and any directory accessible to the Static File Middleware.
> - Serve them via an action method to which authorization is applied. Return a FileResult object:
>
> ```
> public IActionResult BannerImage()
> {
>     var file = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), 
>                             "MyStaticFiles", "images", "banner1.svg");
>
>     return PhysicalFile(file, "image/svg+xml");
> }
> ```

Comment: Yes, I saw this approach also somewhere in the docs. But for just one .html file that wouldn't be a problem but there are multiple folders with different .html files and each .html file contains links to other files, so I need to have some way to check each request. Like in the standard .NET versions I would probably do this with an HttpModule or HttpHandler I guess?